# Caching row ranks in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a column I want to sort by, with periodical updates on the rank (daily).  I currently use this in code

```
get all rows from table order by column

rank = 1
foreach row in table
   update row's rank to rank
   rank++
```

this takes an update for each row in MySQL.  Are there more efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an update with a join:

```
set @rank := 0;

update tbl a join
  (select id, @rank := @rank + 1 as new_rank from tbl order by col) b
  on a.id = b.id set a.rank = b.new_rank;
```

If expecting to have a lot of rows, you'll get the best performance by doing the join against a table that is indexed, e.g.:

```
set @rank := 0;

create temporary table tmp (id int primary key, rank int)
  select id, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank from tbl order by col;

update tbl join tmp on tbl.id = tmp.id set tbl.rank = tmp.rank;
```

Finally, you could potentially make it faster by skipping the update step entirely and swapping in a new table (not always feasible):

```
set @rank := 0;

create table new_tbl (id int primary key, rank int, col char(10),
  col2 char(20)) select id, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank, col, col2
  from tbl order by col;

drop table tbl;
rename table new_tbl to tbl;
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted you.  Any idea what this complexity is?  Assuming all obvious optimizations (keys, etc) are taken?

Comment: yeah best performance is when there's an index, theoretically it should then be rather linear since the primary key is a hash, and you would be updating all the items in the table

Comment: Probably n log n is okay, as long as it doesn't dip into quadratic territory.  I've done some testing and it's substantially faster, even for small values of N.  Only issue might be possible table lock, which I should look into (or maybe de-normalize it to its own table)..